# Audio recording in Nokia symbian OS

Tags: audio-recording, symbian, nokia, s60-5th-edition

I am trying to record voice in symbian S60 5th edition OS. I Am trying to use following code to record the voice as specified in the NOKIA developer's site.

```
  //Create an instance of CMdaAudioRecorderUtility class
    CMdaAudioRecorderUtility iRecorder = CMdaAudioRecorderUtility::NewL(*this);

  //Open file either by using a filename with full path infor or a descriptor
   iRecorder->OpenFileL( aFilename );
   //iRecorder->OpenDesL( aDescriptor );

  //Recording is started
   iRecorder->RecordL();
     ....
     ....
  //Stop Recording
    iRecorder->Stop();
  //Close the recording session
    iRecorder->Close();
```

Any other suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the this pointer in CMdaAudioRecorderUtility::NewL(*this), is pointing to an interface, which you need to implement. And as it has fucntions which are informing you on when the file is opened, closed or other possible states. You would actually need to wait untill you get an event before you start any other operations.

Also see whether the interface functions are giving you any errors.